# How to remove a directory which looks corrupted

Tags: ubuntu, file-management, filesystem-corruption

I am using Ubuntu 9.10.  When I examine a directory, it shows as '?' for user/ownership.

How can I remove it?

```
-rw-r--r--  1 hap497 hap497  1822 2010-01-28 22:48 IntSizeHash.h
d?????????  ? ?       ?           ?                ? .libs/
-rw-r--r--  1 hap497 hap497   194 2010-02-25 12:12 libwebkit_1_0_la-BitmapImage.lo
```

I have tried *rm* and *sudo rm* but get an error:

```
$ sudo rm -Rf .libs
rm: cannot remove `.libs': Input/output error
```

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [removing the file using it's inode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-remove-files-with-inode-number.html):

```
ls -il
```

you should see somehting like:

```
99999 d????????? ? ? ? ? ? .libs/
```

where 99999 is the inode number.  Then try

```
find . -inum 99999 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

you will probably have to 'sudo' the find command, since the ownership is corrupted.

If this directory had files in it, you will end up creating orphans & will need to fsck your disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the ownership to yourself (via sudo chown -R  .libs) then recursively remove the directory (rm -R .libs)...
if that fails: sudo su -; change into directory; remove contents; return to previous directory and remove the directory.